# Akka-Streams: At-Least-Once-Delivery behaviour with Kafka and Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, akka, apache-kafka, reactive-streams

I'm starting with Akka Streams and so far everything is going well. However, I have met with a use case that I don't know how to approach. The scenario is a stream with an ActorPublisher as a source that is consuming messages from Kafka and a subscriber as a sink that updates a Cassandra table.

Kafka ~> some mapping operations ~> Cassandra

The point is that I'd like to explicitly confirm to Kafka every time a message has been successfully processed and inserted into Cassandra so that I could re-read the message in case a disaster happens and the service fails, i.e. some kind of at least once delivery behaviour. How could I approach this in terms of Akka Streams?. Is a supported scenario?.

It's true that I always can configure the Kafka consumer with auto-commit behaviour but I'd rather take control of how I'm reading the messages.

**Update**

Regarding this topic, we're currently evaluating [Reactive Kafka](https://github.com/softwaremill/reactive-kafka) where they've included manual commit in kafka as of 0.8 version (kudos for these guys). This feature would allow us implement the alod behaviour we need.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use a custom stream processing using a PushPullStage as explained in [akka streams documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala/stream-customize.html)

Comment: This sounds as a proper way to get a fine-grained control over the streaming process. I'll have it a look. Thanks!.

Comment: @JuanJoséVázquezDelgado. I'm looking into a similar use-case. Storm has those messaging guarantees, but Akka streams look interesting if it can provide at-least-once messaging guarantees with Kafka. Did you get a chance to look into this? Any interesting conclusions or findings you an share with us?

Comment: I'll try to put into practice [this approach](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/ujluAC4RCPo/AMbkqZidxAoJ) as it was mentioned in the Akka list. I'll update this thread as soon as I come up with a solution. Thanks for your interest.